# Closest point from current point

Tags: algorithm, segment-tree

**Input:**

- A 2-dimentional space of size MxN .
- K points(integer pair) in this 2 dim space.

**Output:**

A point xj, yj from set of K points such that dist(i,j) in minimum where xi, yi is the current point.

**dist(i,j)** : is root mean square distance

Given K << M*N, K~M, K~N, M~N

**Expected time complexity:**

- O(M*N) for each query is definitely not enough.
- O(K) for each query is also not enough.
- Anything better than this will be acceptable.

Comment: "A point xj, yj" seems to imply we are dealing with a two dimensional space. Then you may want to have a look at Voronoi diagrams. Or this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search

Comment: yes you are right. reworded the problem for clarity.

Comment: Are the coordinates integers or real numbers?

Comment: they are inegers, modified question

Comment: I can think of a 2-D segment tree approach, let me know if you have some innovative thoughts. Each query will take O(M*logM*LogN) or vice versa depending on whichever between M,N is smaller.

Comment: There are only finitely many query points possible. You could pre-compute the closest point for each of them. This gives an O(1) query time. Are there any time bounds on the pre-computation?

Comment: I have K queries, each query say if it takes O(K) in worst case without much heavy precomputation, then overall time is k*k . So with heavy precomputation , the precoputation time should be lesser than this to beat the overall time. Any thing better than k^2 overall(ie for all queries) is acceptable.